# Семантическое расстояние между предложениями в word2vec(gensim)

Tags: python, алгоритм, семантика

Какой способ нахождения смысловой близости двух предложений дает самую высокую точность при сравнении предложений из 3-10 слов?
  Лучше находить векторную сумму всех слов каждого предложения, а затем находить расстояние между ними, сравнивать каждое слово с каждым и потом находить среднее расстояние? Еще встречал несколько более сложных вариантов- например с разбиением векторного поля на кластеры и нахождением расстояния между центром кластера и каждым словом исследуемых предложений, что позволяет более точно определить вектор предложения.
  Какой оптимальный вариант в плане быстродействие+качество?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень много зависит от специфики вашего корпуса, имхо. Самое распространенное - через cos-similarity (scikit-learn работает достаточно быстро). Я делал через векторизацию каждого предложения (би-граммы) и потом считал.

Еще можно попробовать через pagerank и вектора находить.

Через использование центроиодов есть вот такой интересный подход (http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W17-1003), там есть ссылка на код на python.